# ngrx and rxjs observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I built a timer in rxjs to use within an angular component. The following code works fine when it is contained within  the same component. The timer countdown is being handled in the following function:

```
  startTimer() {

const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume');
const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
const resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');
const interval$: any = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(-1));
const pause$ = fromEvent(pauseButton, 'click').pipe(mapTo(false));
const resume$ = fromEvent(resumeButton, 'click').pipe(mapTo(true));

this.timer$ = merge(pause$, resume$).pipe(
  startWith(interval$),
  switchMap(val => (val ? interval$ : empty())),
  scan((acc, curr) => (curr ? curr + acc : acc), this.countdownSeconds$),
  takeWhile(v => v >= 0),
)
.subscribe(
  val => {
    this.timeRemaining = val;
    this.timeRemaining = this.timeRemaining + 'tick';
    if (this.timeRemaining === 0) {
      console.log('timer done');
      this.resetTimer();
    }
  },
  () => { this.resetTimer(); });
if (this.timeRemaining === 0) {
  console.log('timer is completed');
}
}
```

But I am now trying to have the emitted value of timeRemaining emit the values through an @Input from the timer in the container component. I have tried every type of observable, subscription imaginable and nothing seems to work. It displays the value but not continuously counting down.

The timer function is listed first then where the time should display in the component, then the function being called to return that within the component. Like I said when access **this.timeRemaining** variable inside the startTimer() function from within a self-contained component it counts down just fine.

```html
<mat-card-subtitle>{{ timeRemaining }}</mat-card-subtitle>

@Input() timeRemaining: number;
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple/small running example (e.g. Stackblitz or Plunker) that shows what you are experiencing?

Comment: I am looking for the correct way to output an observable to show the continuing emitted values of the timer. When it pauses the value pauses. What is happening now is the out only shows the current value when either play or pause is clicked, not continually.  Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it/tree/timer-rebuild